# MySQL Query - Duplicate Payments for 12 months

Tags: mysql

I have a database that has payments called PrePay.  Customers pay 12 months in one payment. 
I need to have this single payment show up as 12 payments (12 records).

Here's my query:

```
SELECT account, startdate, servdef
FROM PAYHIST
WHERE account = 5543
```

`startdate` is a date field

This shows the 3 payments over 3 years:

[image: This shows the 3 payments over 3 years]

I would like to produce 11 payments for each account and servdef after the first payment.  So the 06-22-2018 would have 11 records following it with the months to follow i.e.

[image]

Can you please tell me how to produce the records like this?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry did I not provide enough details?

Comment: Explaining the link defeats the point of providing the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with a table that returns the number of months you want to expand each row to.

```
SELECT account, DATE_ADD(startdate, INTERVAL n MONTH) AS startdate, servdev
FROM PAYHIST
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 AS n
    UNION
    SELECT 1
    UNION
    SELECT 2
    ...
    UNION
    SELECT 11) AS q
WHERE account = 5543
ORDER BY startdate, n
```

Comment: This is perfect @Barmar!  Thank you so much!